# PXE Boot: Alternatives to Exported mounted NFS share

Tags: nfs, pxe

I know I can't export a NFS mount, just a local fs, and this is my likely problem.

I have a PXE server on a virtual box, it has an Ethernet to the regular network and NAS and an Ethernet for a new computer who is going to be PXE booted.  The PXE server gets its ISOs from the NAS, located on the regular Ethernet.  Ideally, the PXE'd box would see only a local FS and all the mounted stuff is hidden away, the server would act as a proxy.

/var/lib/tftpboot is exported on the PXE server which has a mount called "PXE"
192.168.2.1:/mnt/Nas/PXE is mounted there.   192.168.1.20 is my PXE server which assigns IPs via DHCP.

The new computer can access the PXE server but it can't get to the NAS.  I can boot a vmlinuz image off the NAS.  But it crashes soon as it tries to setup a nfs of its own to the NaS.

netboot from 192.168.1.20 :/var/lib/tftpboot/PXE/GParted
Trying to nfsmount -o nolock -o ro 192.168.1.20:/var/lib/tftpboot/PXE/GParted /live/medium  fails/times outs.  It's trying to mount a remotely mounted NFS.

What should I do instead?

Comment: You probably need to setup a gateway between the two networks. Alternatively, if you only want the nfs for readonly installation, you might look at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315690/119298) I gave to a question on how you might re-export a cifs filesystem by using an intermediate fuse filesystem, which you could try on your PXE server to re-export the NFS.

Comment: Could you post your `dhpd.conf` and your pxe config? (probably your `default` in some subdir of `tftpboot`)

Comment: The NAS with all the files is located here:  10.1.100.128:/mnt/NasVol/NasSMB/PXE  (it is exported)
The server can reach it on eth 0. DHCP.conf and default are on https://pastebin.com/L2TsbkTM


Eth1 is NATd Internet
Eth2 is the PXE DHCP.

ip route list:

default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1
10.1.10.0/24 via 10.1.100.100 dev eth0
10.1.100.0/24 via 10.1.100.100 dev eth0
10.1.100.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.100.152
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.153
192.168.201.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.201.20