# Selecting a section of a file

Tags: awk, sed

I've a file formatted like this:

```
title1
        line
        line

title2
        line
        line

        line

title3
        line
        line
```

and I'd like to extract the section under `title2` and remove the indent.  I'm currently using `sed` (but `awk` or a shell script would be suitable in my context, sadly not languages like `perl` or `python`) like this:

```
sed -n -e '/^title2$/,/^[a-zA-Z]/ { /^[a-zA-Z]/ d ; s/^[ \t]*// ; p }'
```

but that leaves a logically blank line at the end (logically because it may have blanks or tabs).  I want to get rid of it. Note that there may be other logically blank lines in the part to keep (or a `/^[ \t]*$/ d` would have made the work).  Thus I'd like this result:

```
line
line

line
```

I can do it with an additional `sed -e '$d'` but I'd like to know if it is possible to avoid that second process.

Answer (score 1):

I used the hold space and I ended up with

```
sed -ne '/^title2$/,/^[a-zA-Z]/ { /^title2$/ { n; h; b; } ; /^[a-zA-Z]/ d; H; x; s/[ \t]*//; P; s/.*\n//; x }'
```

which seems to handle the cases I care for correctly.

Comment: The last `x` isn't needed.
After processing `title2`, you'll basically always have the previous line and the current line in the pattern space and just the **_current line_** in **the hold space** after the first `x` then you clean space(`s/[ \t]*//`), print the previous line(`P`), remove the previous line from the pattern space(`s/.*\n//`) which leaves just the **_current line_** in **the pattern space**. So, the hold space and pattern space are identical by the time you get to the last `x`. This post has inspired me to learn a lot by the way =)

Answer (score 0):

- if it is a "pure" line (no tab or white), delete it also with `/^$/`
- for "logical" blank use `/^\s*$/`

  ```
  sed -n -e '/^title2:/,/^[a-zA-Z]/ { /^[a-zA-Z]/ d ; /^$/ d ; s/^[ \t]*// ; p }'
  ```

where

- `/^$/` match start-line,end-of-line
- `/^\s*$/` match start-line,zero or more space or tab,end-of-line

Comment: Sadly the last lines may have tabs or whites, as can the logically empty lines in the middle of the part to keep.

Comment: I see, I adress space and tabs but not middle blank line. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/title2/,/^\S/ { //b; /^\s*$/ { N; /\n\S/q; P; D }; s/^\s*//; p }'
```

I initially did this to get @Archemar 's attention. I'd really appreciate it if you could **please** reply to **[my comment in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315637/is-it-possible-to-create-a-nfs-share-from-a-cifs-mounted-directory#comment1034317_315637)** whenever you have time. Even if the answer is "I don't know". THANKS.

In my bash shell, at least, it works without `-e`. Just curious why is it ever needed? And if [`\s` or `\S`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) isn't supported, you can replace them with `[ \t]`'s and `[^ \t]`'s, respectively.

Breakdown for people who were as clueless as I was when I first saw this question:

- `-n` turns off auto print
- `/title2/,/^\S/` is a range for `sed` to search in (from the line of the first occurrence of the string, "`title2`" to the next line that starts with a non-space character[i.e. `title3`] **inclusively**)
- `{` just means apply the enclosed commands to the range or pattern I just specified

  - `//b` allows the following commands to not apply to the start and end of the range.
    More literally, if you match `title2` or `^\S` just branch to the end of the script(`b`)(process the next line in the file, if there are any left) because in [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html#Regexp-Addresses) ([BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1#Sed_Regular_Expressions) says similarly, not sure if there's any other version of `sed`)

    > ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match
  - `/^\s*$/` matches the "logically blank" lines in the range.
  - `{`

    - `N; /\n\S/q;` So if, it's a "logically blank" line, `N` adds the next line to the pattern space and then if that next line is the next title, it quits processing altogether(`q`), so neither the "logically blank" line nor the next title are printed.
    - `P; D` If the "logically blank" line **isn't** followed by the next title, then **just** the "logically blank" line is printed(`P`), and then **just** the "logically blank" line is deleted from the pattern space leaving the next line that was added to the pattern space by `N` to be processed from the beginning of the script(`D`)
  - `}`
  - `s/^\s*//; p` takes away the spaces and tabs at the beginning of the line and prints the formatted line
- `}`

@Archemar please **[HELP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315637/is-it-possible-to-create-a-nfs-share-from-a-cifs-mounted-directory#comment1034317_315637)**